# Does the number of xml layout files alone affect the performance of an Android app?

Tags: android, performance, android-layout

I am working on a dynamic Multilevel Expandable `ListView` for an Android app and I have to create an xml layout file for each level I want to have. I am wondering whether an app performance is affected by the sheer number of xml layout files it has.

The question is based on the following method for creating a Multilevel Expandable `ListView`: http://www.androidhub4you.com/2014/07/android-multilevel-expandable-listview.html

For the code in the link to work, you need to add three xml files; row_first.xml, row_second.xml and row_third.xml. One for each row.

Thank you very much for your time and assistance in this matter.

Comment: Please review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question.

Comment: For each view in your app, Android goes through three steps to render on the screen: measure, layout, and draw. The more views your app has, the more time it will take to measure, layout, and draw. And your apps performance will be affected.

Comment: For the code in the link to work you need at have three xml files row_first.xml, row_second.xml and row_third.xml